# Retrieve the public pgp key of a Maven hosted library

Tags: maven, pgp

I've been trying to figure out how to retrieve the public facing PGP key of libraries hosted on Maven repositories (for instance MavenCentral and Google's mirrors).

Is there a way that these keys can be retrieved through a url in some way?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the PGP key?

Comment: @JFabianMeier not that the use-case is important for the question at hand, but I am looking into performing Gradle dependency verification using the signature used when publishing public packages.  As it seems not all entities make it easy to find these keys (Apache and Jetbrains do for instance) I was hoping to try to figure out a way to extract them from the public repos.